# Spring Data MongoDB - sort by multiple fields does not work

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, sorting, spring-data-mongodb

I have a MongoRepository with the following method:

`Position findFirstByDeviceIdAndSensorUsedIsIn(String deviceId, String[] sensorsUsed, Sort sort);`

And i call it like this:

```
return posRepo.findFirstByDeviceIdAndSensorUsedIsIn(deviceId, VALID_SENSORS, new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "Time"), new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "TimeReceived")));
```

VALID_SENSORS is a String-Array with 2 entries.

The problem now is, that it sorts by Time but the second dimension (TimeReceived) is random.
The TRACE-Output of the mongodb driver is:

> com.mongodb.TRACE                        : find: company.position { "$query" : { "device_id" : "testId" , "sensor_used" : { "$in" : [ "CELL_LOCATE" , "GPS"]}} , "$orderby" : { "time" : -1 , "time_rcvd" : -1}}

When i try the following query with my mongoclient robomongo the order is correct. Here is the query:

```
 db.getCollection('position').find({device_id:'testdevice'}).sort({time:-1,time_‌​rcvd:-1}).limit(5)
```

What can cause this strange behavior?

**EDIT:**
I also tried the following code in my spring application:

```
TypedAggregation<Position> agg = newAggregation(Position.class,
            match(where("deviceId").is(deviceId).andOperator(where("sensorUsed").in(VALID_SENSORS))),
            sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "time"),
            sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "timeReceived"),
            limit(1)
    );

    AggregationResults<Position> result = template.aggregate(agg, Position.class);
```

But it does not work either! :(

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [Aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/), which was introduced in Mongo 2.2.

[`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) is the important operation, which duplicates each document in the aggregation pipeline, doing so once per array element. You'll want to unwind both `time` and `time_rcvd`, and then [`$sort`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) them.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer.

Why does it work when i try it with a mongo client like RoboMongo?
Code:
`db.getCollection('position').find({device_id:'testdevice'}).sort({time_rcvd:-1}).limit(1)`

Can you please explain the difference?
Or can you please provide some sample code for your solution. I do not understand why i need unwind.

Comment: In this query, you've only used sort on one field in the documents' array.

Comment: You are right. Sorry my mistake.
Here is the right query:
`db.getCollection('position').find({device_id:'testdevice'}).sort({time:-1,time_rcvd:-1}).limit(5)`

For all entities where time is equal they are sorted by time_rcvd and the order is correct.

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide an example bson document, just to make sure we're on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

With the aggregation framework, you can do the following:

```
TypedAggregation<Position> agg = newAggregation(Position.class,
    match(
        where("deviceId").is(deviceId).andOperator(
            where("sensorUsed").in(VALID_SENSORS)
        )
    ),
    sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "time").and(Sort.Direction.DESC, "timeReceived"),
    limit(1)
);

AggregationResults<Position> result = template.aggregate(agg, Position.class);
```